# Azure Devops Unzip artifact and Then Upload to Site

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am working on my Azure devops Integration. I currently have this release made:
[image: Azure Release]
Now my Pipeline Artifact is zipped, and i need it to be unzipped before getting uploaded to my site, what do i need to do in order to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could download the Artifact via the task `Download Pipeline Artifacts`, then add task `Extract files` and add the task `FTP upload` to uploaded to your site.

[image]